# ID not found with Appium and Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

The ID "username" is found with a compile on Galaxy J2 Prime but the same compile on Galaxy S6 not found the id "username". The response of console is:

*[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"username","context":"","multiple":false}}
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"username","context":"","multiple":false}}
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'username' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.vtrapp.ventas:id/username]
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=android:id/username]
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=username]
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=username, INSTANCE=0]
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'username' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.vtrapp.ventas:id/username]
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=android:id/username]
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=username]
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=username, INSTANCE=0]
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
[debug] [35m[W3C (2f6e58e6)][39m Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
[debug] [35m[W3C (2f6e58e6)][39m     at AndroidDriver.findElOrEls (C:\Users\Haibu15\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\find.js:75:11)
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/2f6e58e6-f3db-4d75-bace-39f457fbc1b3/element [39m[33m404[39m [90m21577 ms - 436[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-4E9I01S', ip: '169.254.4.145', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver*

And code is:

```
public class StartAppVentas {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService( new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"))
            .withAppiumJS(new File(
            "C:\\Users\\Haibu15\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js")));


    service.start();

    //Set the Desired Capabilities
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy S6");
    //caps.setCapability("udid", "420039359b4f2433"); //Device ID Galaxy J2 Prime 
    caps.setCapability("udid", "1015fa58982f0503"); //Device ID Galaxy S6
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.vtrapp.ventas");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.vtrapp.ventas.MainActivity");
    caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

    //Instantiate Appium Driver
    try {
            AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("isalinass");
            driver.findElement(By.id("contraseña")).sendKeys("Nacho0");
            driver.findElement(By.id("recordarme")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("recordarme")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("ingresar")).click();
            //driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.));

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    service.stop();

}
```

}

**Note: I Used "uiautomatorviewer.bat" for check the id of the elements and it's correct and the app open correctly  on the phone but the ID "username" is not found.**

Comment: Have you tried using Appium Inspector to look for the item? Are you sure it is displayed the same way on both phones?

Comment: for the both phone the "id" is visible in uiautomator, i not used appium inspector. Maybe the compile is the problem?